# Trouble using JavaScript dropdown more than once on the same page

Tags: javascript, dropdownbox

I'm using this code for a drop down function in a table, and it's working great.  However, when I try to use it more than once on the same page, One is corrupting the information of the other.  I've tried changing the id settings but it didn't work.  What do I need to do to so I can use this multiple time on a singe page.  I'm using Wordpress and placing the script in the header.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function openPop(){
    var Sel_Ind = document.getElementById('myURLs').selectedIndex;
    var popUrl = document.getElementById('myURLs').options[Sel_Ind].value;
    winpops=window.open(popUrl,"","width=400,height=338,resizable,")
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="myURLs" onChange="javascript:openPop();">
        <option value="">Select a page...</option>
        <option value="http://news.bbc.co.uk">News</option>
        <option value="http://www.the-company.com">Music</option>
        <option value="http://www.b3ta.com">Laughs</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com">Search</option>
        <option value="http://www.sitepoint.com/forums">Help</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Make sure you don't duplicate IDs.

Comment: Only one unique ID per document.  Also, you might want to use `getElementsByTagName('select')` and loop through its results, otherwise I think your question requires too much effort to answer and you need to read more of the JavaScript documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you have hardcoded ids inside the onChange handler. Instead, what you can do is to pass the select element of which the onChange event fires into the handler function and use that to further processing.

```
<select id="myURLs1" onChange="openPop(this)">
    <option value="">Select a page...</option>
    <option value="http://news.bbc.co.uk">News</option>
    <option value="http://www.the-company.com">Music</option>
    <option value="http://www.b3ta.com">Laughs</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Search</option>
    <option value="http://www.sitepoint.com/forums">Help</option>
</select>

<select id="myURLs2" onChange="openPop(this)">
    <option value="">Select a page...</option>
    <option value="http://news.bbc.co.uk">News</option>
    <option value="http://www.the-company.com">Music</option>
    <option value="http://www.b3ta.com">Laughs</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Search</option>
    <option value="http://www.sitepoint.com/forums">Help</option>
</select>
```

Then in the handler function accept the select box into a parameter.

```
function openPop(sel){
    var popUrl = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    winpops=window.open(popUrl,"","width=400,height=338,resizable,")
};
```

This way, you can have as many as select boxes you want and handler will behave correctly.

Check this fiddle for this implementation.

http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/awc6o9ju/